# Is it possible to load a view based on the url with angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I want to be able to have users goto `www.myurl.com/#/login` and be taken to the specified view.  Same for if they are on a specific view, if they refresh I would want them to be taken to the same view again. However currently no matter what the extension it will always take you to the home page on start up.  Is there likely to be an error in my code or does angular routing not behave like that?

```
fcApp.config(function ($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/',
{
    templateUrl: 'html/frontPage.html'
})
.when('/login',
{
    templateUrl: 'html/frontPage.html'
})
.when('/home',
{
    templateUrl: 'html/home.html'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});
```

Comment: You just run wrong url pattern, miss `#`. Try: `www.myurl.com/#/login` or something else like `www.myurl.com/#/*`. Anyways I suggest you to use `$state` aka `stateProvider`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write the # in my question, I get the described behaviour with the hash.  I will read up on stateProvider though, thanks.

Comment: The problem is in code you're not showing. Please post a complete example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Comment: Yes you were right, there was a rouge re-direct causing it.  I have solved the problem, but I asked this question wanting to know what the expected behavior was with the ng routing in general and you answered that.  Thanks!